# Multiple Fields based on drop down in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

Here is my fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/harshithanaidu1991/6vx7ej9d/

i have given default select drop down value as 'One Single Occupancy' but the table is not showing when change the drop down option then only the table is coming .
How do i make to display default one table as per the first value from the drop down.

Here is my javascript code:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#amount').change(function(){
  $('#groups').empty();
  var group = '';
  var number = parseInt($(this).val());
  for(var i=1;i<=number;i++){
   group += '<div id="group">' +
    '<h1 style=" font-size: 14px;color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><u>GUEST DETAILS : '+i+'</u></h1>'+
   '<table class="tabpasdding" width="100%" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">'+
          '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />'+
          '<tr>'+
            '<td width="50%" align="left">'+
                '<table width="100%" align="left">'+


   '<tr>'+
     '<td ><label>Full Name <span style="color:red">*</span></label></td>'+
     '<td ><input type="text" id="pname'+i+'" name="pname'+i+'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" onkeydown="testForEnter();"></td>'+
   '</tr>'+

    '<tr>'+
    '<td ><label>Passport Number <span style="color:green">#</span> </label></td>'+
     '<td ><input type="text" name="ppassport'+i+'" id="ppassport'+i+'" class="form-control"  autocomplete="off" onkeydown="testForEnter();"></td>'+
   '</tr>'+

  '</table>'+
            '</td>'+
            '<td width="50%" align="right">'+
                '<table width="100%" align="right">'+

  '<tr><td><label class="">Check In Date & Time </label></td><td> <div class="input-group date form_datetime " data-date="1979-09-16T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">'+
                   '<input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" id="checkindatetime'+i+'" name="checkindatetime'+i+'">'+
                   '<span class="input-group-addon" style="width:17%"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>'+
         '<span class="input-group-addon"  style="width:17%"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>'+
               '</div> </td></tr>'+
  '<tr><td><label>Check Out Date & Time </label></td><td>  <div class="input-group date form_datetime " data-date="1979-09-16T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">'+
                   '<input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" id="checkoutdatetime'+i+'" name="checkoutdatetime'+i+'">'+
                   '<span class="input-group-addon" style="width:17%"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>'+
         '<span class="input-group-addon"  style="width:17%"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>'+
               '</div> </td></tr>'+


  '</table>'+
            '</td>'+
          '</tr>'+

  '</table>' +
  '    <p>&nbsp;</p>'+

   '</div>';
   }
   $('#groups').append(group);
  });
  });
```

And here is my html code:

```
   <table class="tabpasdding" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td><label>Select Preference :</label> </td>
          <td>
            <select id="amount">

              <option value="1" selected>One Single Occupancy</option>
              <option value="2">Two Single Occupancy</option>
              <option value="2">One Double Occupancy</option>
              <option value="4">Two Double Occupancy</option>
              <option value="3">One Single & One Double Occupancy</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div id="groups">
      </div>
```

You can check the fiddle here:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/harshithanaidu1991/9hbnLky0/13/
```

Please help me

Comment: you have to append the "#groups" div first and add the table with the value(in your case i=1) before you go in the change function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below snippet. 
Created a function to generate HTML based on the selected number of the dropdown. And placed that function in on change event of the dropdown to generate HTML when dropdown values change. And same function put in document.ready when page will load the HTML will generated based on default selected dropdown value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 //by default generate html based on the default selected value.
  $('#groups').empty();    
  var number = parseInt($("#amount").val());
  createHTML(number);
  
  $('#amount').change(function(){
    $('#groups').empty();    
    number = parseInt($(this).val());
    createHTML(number);
  });
});

function createHTML(number){
 var group = '';
  for(var i=1;i<=number;i++){
    group += '<div id="group">' +
      '<h1 style=" font-size: 14px;color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><u>GUEST DETAILS : '+i+'</u></h1>'+
      '<table class="tabpasdding" width="100%" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">'+
      '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />'+
      '<tr>'+
      '<td width="50%" align="left">'+
      '<table width="100%" align="left">'+


      '<tr>'+
      '<td ><label>Full Name <span style="color:red">*</span></label></td>'+
      '<td ><input type="text" id="pname'+i+'" name="pname'+i+'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" onkeydown="testForEnter();"></td>'+
      '</tr>'+

      '<tr>'+
      '<td ><label>Passport Number <span style="color:green">#</span> </label></td>'+
      '<td ><input type="text" name="ppassport'+i+'" id="ppassport'+i+'" class="form-control"  autocomplete="off" onkeydown="testForEnter();"></td>'+
      '</tr>'+

      '</table>'+
      '</td>'+
      '<td width="50%" align="right">'+
      '<table width="100%" align="right">'+

      '<tr><td><label class="">Check In Date & Time </label></td><td> <div class="input-group date form_datetime " data-date="1979-09-16T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">'+
      '<input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" id="checkindatetime'+i+'" name="checkindatetime'+i+'">'+
      '<span class="input-group-addon" style="width:17%"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>'+
      '<span class="input-group-addon"  style="width:17%"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>'+
      '</div> </td></tr>'+
      '<tr><td><label>Check Out Date & Time </label></td><td>  <div class="input-group date form_datetime " data-date="1979-09-16T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">'+
      '<input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" id="checkoutdatetime'+i+'" name="checkoutdatetime'+i+'">'+
      '<span class="input-group-addon" style="width:17%"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>'+
      '<span class="input-group-addon"  style="width:17%"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>'+
      '</div> </td></tr>'+


      '</table>'+
      '</td>'+
      '</tr>'+

      '</table>' +
      '    <p>&nbsp;</p>'+
      //       '<p style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;text-transform:uppercase"><input type="checkbox" name="billingtoo" onclick="FillBilling(this.form)">'+
      // ' Check this box if check in and check out Details same</p>'+
      '</div>';
  }
  $('#groups').append(group);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tabpasdding" width="100%">
            <tr>
              <td><label>Select Preference :</label> </td>
              <td>
                <select id="amount">
               
                  <option value="1" selected>One Single Occupancy</option>
                  <option value="2">Two Single Occupancy</option>
                  <option value="2">One Double Occupancy</option>
                  <option value="4">Two Double Occupancy</option>
                  <option value="3">One Single & One Double Occupancy</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <div id="groups">
          </div>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly ..But my date picker is not coming for the field check in date & time. ..@Rahul Patel

Comment: Thanks, I am not getting you. You want datepicker for check in date&time input?

Comment: Yeah ..with using JavaScript date picker was coming as soon as i  made this with JavaScript then date picker disappears..

Comment: You can easily apply datepicker using jquery-ui datepicker.
Please refer : https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in a function like:

```
function generateDetails()
{
......
}

call it on document on load and call the same on 

$('#amount').change(function(){
  generateDetails();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So for this problem to fix you need use trigger function in your code. It will run once change function without change. I have updated your jsfiddle.
After change function writedown this:

```
        $('#groups').append(group);
                             });$('#amount').trigger("change");
```